# What kind of files belongs in a maven repo?

Tags: maven

I have made a decent effort trying to google this but can't seem to find some good guidelines for this.

I suspect *.jar and *.pom are obvious candidates but there might be others.

As one should not just use a maven repo as a file server I guess there are files that should likely never go there (like *.java).

Is there er definitive guide or at least a best practice someone could refer to?

And what about "fat jars" *.ear and *.war.... do they belong in a maven repo? I'm leaning towards no, but maybe my understanding of what a maven repo should provide is just limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically a Maven repo can have a jar or a war or esb(jboss archive) or any other file type. Think of your local .m2 or a Nexus repository that can have any file type that is an outcome of a build. But for dependency purposes it is almost always the JAR files that are in the repo you would need. HTH